# Add Printer using TCP/IP or hostname option is not available

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

"Add printer using TCP/IP address or host name" option is not available in 'Control Panel->Device and Printers->Add printer' in Windows server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Print Management - Select Print Servers - Right Click Go-to properties - Click on the Security TAB and click on full Access for Everyone .. tried and tested...